# How can I make a field in a meteor Simple Schema equal to a js variable and still let the user fill out the rest of the simple schema?

Tags: javascript, html, mongodb, meteor, schema

I am making a meteor web app where the user will click on a html button.  Once this button is clicked, the user needs to be directed to another page with some forms generated by a meteor simple schema package.  The first field in the simple schema needs to automatically be given a string value of "hello" and then the rest of the fields in the simple schema will be filled out by the user with the input fields on the page. What I am unsure about is how to get the first value automatically set to this string value. Here is some of the code I have:

The simple schema declaration:

```
LobbySchema = new SimpleSchema({
  game: {
    type: String,
    label: "Game"
  },
  console: {
    type: String,
    label: "Console"
  },
  players: {
    type: Number,
    label: "Players"
  },
  mic: {
    type: Boolean,
    label: "Mic"
  },
  note: {
    type: String,
    label: "Note"
  },
  gamertag: {
    type: String,
    label: "Gamertag"
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    label: "Created At",
    autoValue: function(){
      return new Date()
    },
    autoform: {
      type: "hidden"
    }
  }
});
```

The first field there in the schema "game" needs to be given the value "hello" when the html button is clicked.  Right now I can assign that value to a javascript variable using the button by having an onclick function:

```
function getElementText(elementID){
   var elementText = "hello";
}
```

The button would call the getElementText function and have the elementText variable equal "hello". Now I need to assign the the first field in the simple schema to this variable value, "hello", then have it so the user can now fill out the rest of the schema with the input fields, automatically generated into the html with this code:

```
{{> quickForm collection="Lobby" id="insertLobbyForm" type="insert" class="newLobbyForm"}}
```

If you do not feel like providing the answer (maybe it happens to be more complicated than I think) then I would be very happy to receive a link to a site that might help me with this. I am also very willing to explain anything about the question if I did not explain the situation well enough above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the AutoForm hooks like this:

```
AutoForm.hooks({
    app_create: {
        before: {
            method: function (doc) {
                // Do whatever assignment you need to do here, 
                // like doc['game'] = "hello";  //then 
                return doc;
            }
        },
        onSuccess: function (formType, result) {

        },
        onError: function (formType, error) {

        }
    }
});
```

Where here `app_create` is the id of the form you're sending with Autoform.

Comment: this seems like a promising answer, could you link me to a site where there is documentation on it? I'm not sure I fully understand what an autoform hook is. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform/blob/0097d5fe0e1c7456b2fd5ed49358576b35a34fb8/README.md#callbackshooks

Comment: I cant figure out what hooks are for the life of me please help

Comment: show what you tried. the code above allow you to edit the doc before submitting, so you can fill in the fields you want with your js variable (before submittng to server)

Comment: if what you wantis fill in the form before showing to the user all you need is to assign the variable to the 'value' field of the input in the template.

Comment: autofrm takes care of sending the form. if you use methods, it will run your method, if you use the monimongo add/update it will submit to minimingo and DDP takes care of pushing to the server.

Comment: oh, I guess i should have mentioned that the 'app_create' tag is the name of the form you are sending. Sorry if I omitted that.